# How to hear voice from headphone plugged in front panel in linux?

Tags: audio, front-panel

I want to hear voice from my headphone plugged in front panel.
Enable AC97 in my bios.

```
Advanced--onboard Devices Configuration--front Panel type--AC97
```

In windows system ,i can hear voice after setting  connector settings with AC97 Front Panel.

[image]

Now reboot and enter into my linux--debian(dual os:win10+debian),i can't hear voice from my headphone plugged in front panel,how to set it then?

Answer (score 0):

Input command:

```
alsamixer
```

[image]

Move cursor on `Front` and `Front Mic` ,click `m` to change the status `MM` into `OO`.

[image]